# open the application by notification

Tags: android, notifications

I want when the user click on the notification it return to the app or start a new activity , I tried all the codes here but it close my application suddenly . if anyone can help me to modify my code below I will be grateful . Thank u .

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    long futureInMillis;
    // SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    int uniqueCode = preferences.getInt("uniqueCode", 0) + 1;
    preferences.edit().putInt("uniqueCode", uniqueCode).apply();

    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month); // January has value 0
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    //calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM );
    //futureInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    //futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (value * 1000);
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION, getNotification(" "+taskn+" moved to q1 "));
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), uniqueCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);




    return rootView;
}


private Notification getNotification(String content) {

Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getActivity());
    query.whereEqualTo("TaskN",taskn);
    query.whereEqualTo("TheUser", username);

    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            object.put("Quadric", "q1");
            object.saveInBackground();
        }

    });

    builder.setContentTitle("Time management.");
    builder.setContentText(content);
   // notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, text, contentIntent);
    // builder.setSound();
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_home);
   return builder.build();
}
```

i get this in logCat :

```
    04-02 13:42:24.161    4030-4030/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/OpenGLRenderer﹕       Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-02 13:42:24.161    4030-4030/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/OpenGLRenderer﹕       MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
04-02 13:42:24.173    4030-4030/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/OpenGLRenderer﹕       Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
04-02 13:42:24.185    4030-4030/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/OpenGLRenderer﹕      MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
04-02 13:49:50.309    4118-4118/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/TaskStackBuilder﹕      Bad ComponentName while traversing activity parent metadata
04-02 13:49:50.309    4118-4118/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/AndroidRuntime﹕       FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 4118
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:            android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:     ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.NotificationActivity}
        at android.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack(TaskStackBuilder.java:180)
        at android.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack(TaskStackBuilder.java:151)
        at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.NotificationFragment.onCreateView(NotificationFragment.java:80)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/           info.androidhive.slidingmenu.NotificationActivity}
            at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:242)
            at android.app.TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack(TaskStackBuilder.java:167)
```

when i try this code :

```
     intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION, getNotification(" "+taskn+" moved to q1 "));
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), uniqueCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getActivity());
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    pendingIntent = stackBuilder
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);





  private Notification getNotification(String content) {

Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getActivity());
    query.whereEqualTo("TaskN",taskn);
    query.whereEqualTo("TheUser", username);

    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            object.put("Quadric", "q1");
            object.saveInBackground();
        }

    });

    builder.setContentTitle("Time management.");
    builder.setContentText(content);
   // notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, text, contentIntent);
    // builder.setSound();
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_home);
   return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: "it close my application suddenly" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: maybe it is different if i build a notification using builder?and i will post the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Try my code to create notification.

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity2.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0,
            resultIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Set the Notification's Click Behavior
    //mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.xxxx);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
    int notifyID = Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                .setContentTitle("My App name")
                .setTicker("My App descrition")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.xxxx)
                .setLargeIcon(
                        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET) // doesn't show any part of this notification on the lock screen.
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_view, getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.foreground_notification_dim), resultPendingIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(
                notifyID,
                mNotifyBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: What is your API vesion?

Comment: it's 22 and the min is 19